# JQuery - change window location after submit by pressing enter

Tags: jquery, forms, window, location, submit

I'm trying to change the window location after a submit caused by the user pressing enter.  Now, it's probably XSS protection that's stopping this from working, but I'm thinking there must be a way to do this.  If not, then the answer goes to whoever can confirm that what I'm trying to do isn't possible.

What I'm doing is:

```
    $("form").submit(function () {

        window.location = window.location.pathname + "?address=" + escape($("#address").val());
    });
```

This is because I'm using an .aspx page, and I'm submitting it to itself.  However I'm trying to provide a simple interface where the page does it's processing based on an address value passed on the querystring, so I'm trying not to use a hidden field to pass the address value, and just use the querystring mechanism.  Am I banging my head up against a security restriction?  I could just use a hidden field and check for this in the code behind if no querystring is found after postback - is this the only option?

Comment: going offline now so I'll pick up responses in around 16 hours time

Answer (score 1):

- The problem turned out to be that the form submit 'action' overrides the javascript 'redirection'
- I got the desired result by passing things the usual way via form inputs, and checking their values now in the code behind, if there's nothing passed on the querystring

Comment: Code example of solution used would still be nice.